# How do I call a secure WCF Rest service from javascript client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, wcf, rest

This should be easy but I am not able to find the solution.
**Is it possible to call a secure wcf service from javascript client?**
 I have running secure WCF Rest service. I have added a .X509 certificate using makecert.exe to iy. I have hosted my service on IIS and I have added the certificate to my service.

I have a javascript client for calling the service. Now when I hit the service I get the eror: **https:/192.168.0.5/Rest/ net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE**.

**How can I make my javascript client to access the service??**
Here is my  service's web.config:

```
   <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service name="RestDemo.RestDemo" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">

            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="https://localhost/RestDemo/RestDemo.svc" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestDemo.IRestDemo" behaviorConfiguration="web">
              <!--<identity>
                <dns value="localhost"/>
              </identity>-->

            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="RestDemo.IRestDemo" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>

          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="web">

              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />

              </security>
            </binding>

          </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
              <serviceCredentials>
                <clientCertificate>
                  <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"
                                 trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />

                </clientCertificate>
                <serviceCertificate findValue="ServerCertificate"
                  storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                  storeName="My"
                  x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
              </serviceCredentials>
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="/RestDemo.svc" />
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">

              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>


**Here is my javascript client:**

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnCall').click(function () {
                debugger;
                var name = "test";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    //   url: "http://localhost:49620/RestDemo.svc/DoWork/"+name,
                    url: "https://192.168.0.15/Rest/",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function (xml) {
                        alert("success");
                        var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
                        alert(xmlText);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Does the browser you are running the javascript in trust your self-signed certificate?

Comment: Did you properly activated `SSL` in `IIS` for that service?

Comment: @stuartd:  I am able to browse to service from IIS ..service opens just fine

Comment: @Mirjalal Talishinski: Yes as  I was able to add the certificate to the service hosted on IIS successfully... and I can browse to the service  from  IIS

Comment: I have figured some options for solve this problem:
1) remove `httpsGetUrl="/RestDemo.svc"` 
2) change `httpGetEnabled="false"` to `httpGetEnabled="true"`
3) in ajax call you wrote `url: "https://192.168.0.15/Rest/"`. Change it to 
`url: "https://192.168.0.15/YourServiceName.svc/yourMethodName"`



p.s I know these `1)` and `2)` *looks stupid*. But for solving the problem you should try these *options*. 

Hope to help.

Comment: @ Mirjalal Talishinski: I want to add .x509 certificate security to my web service ..If i remove these How would it be a secure connection??